# TinyMCE: how to let user mark text when "readonly: true;"

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I want to let users select (and copy) text within TinyMCE.

<strike>I'm not quite sure, but it seems regarding security that browsers don't allow that.</strike>

This Codepen is from the official TinyMCE site:
https://codepen.io/tinymce/pen/NGegZK

Here you can select text.

When you add there the following parameter in the 2nd line of the JavaScript as followed, then you can't longer select text.

```
  readonly: true,
```

How can I set "readonly: true" and let the user still select text?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue as you. What i don't get is why tinyMCE has this behavior while web browsers permit selection in readonly inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced this problem too. Moreover, the inability to select text is nothing compared to the inability to click links. I've submitted an [issue](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/4396) about this a while ago, but there is still no reaction.

You can use a workaround for now ([codepen](https://codepen.io/thorn0/pen/xaYoOb)):

```
  readonly: 1,
  setup: function(editor) {
    editor.on('SwitchMode', function() {
      if (editor.readonly) {
        editor.readonly = 1;
      }
    });
  }
```

It exploits the fact that the event-blocking code uses strict comparison internally (`readonly === true`) while the rest of the code works fine with any other truthy value, e.g. `1`. Of course, this hack might stop working after an update in the future, but it's much better than nothing.

Update: better switch to the `inline` mode ([codepen](https://codepen.io/thorn0/pen/LJQKzR)) if you use this hack. Otherwise clicking links leads to a mess.

Comment: I love you man! It works perfect! Indeed, the open-link-thing leads to a mess. But I need to avoid the inline: true property and found another solution: add with jquery to all links target="_blank". Here is the fork: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dqKzjz

Comment: We can't do this in `setup` where the iframe document hasn't been created yet. Use `init_instance_callback` instead. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PdaJxo

Comment: Also notice how I used event delegation to cover the links that can be added to the editor later. However, modifying the content of the editor (adding the `target` attribute) is probably not something we want. `window.open` + `event.preventDefault` is probably a better idea.

Comment: Now it works on version 5.1.4 if it's possible for you to upgrade

Answer (score 2):

I have checked the source code of the lastest nightly and it seems that the behavior is hardcoded. All events are discarded if the editor is in readonly mode. Which means that selection events are discarded too :

```
  var isListening = function (editor) {
    return !editor.hidden && !editor.readonly;
  };
  var fireEvent = function (editor, eventName, e) {
    if (isListening(editor)) {
      editor.fire(eventName, e);
    } else if (isReadOnly(editor)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };
```

I might be wrong but I don't think you can change this behavior through customization.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your post, you can you help how to implement these both functions? Somewhere when in the object which is given the .init({})-function of TinyMCE?

Comment: As I said, at the moment you have no choice but to modify TinyMCE source code yourself to select text while in readOnly mode. You could submit a ticket to TinyMCE to provide this option too. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue for achieve readonly mode by myself,  I would create an iframe dom node and put the editor's html segment into it.

```
  renderReportPreview = contentHtml => {
    const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe[name=preview]')
    if (iframe) {
      const cssLink = document.createElement('link')
      // cssLink.href = 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css'
      // I prefer semantic-ui, semantic-ui is more like tinyMce style
      cssLink.href = 'https://cdn.bootcss.com/semantic-ui/2.3.1/semantic.min.css'
      cssLink.rel = 'stylesheet'
      cssLink.type = 'text/css'
      iframe.contentWindow.document.head.appendChild(cssLink)
      // I escape the origin editor's content, so I need decode them back
      iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = htmlDecode(contentHtml)
      const allTables = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.querySelectorAll(
        'table'
      )
      Array.from(allTables).forEach(table => {
        // ui celled table for compatible semantic-ui
        // table table-bordered for compatible bootstrap
        table.className = 'ui celled table table-bordered'
      })
      this.setState({
        previewRendered: true,
      })
    }
  }
```

More detail on https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/4575

Answer (score 0):

It was previously possible to select text in readonly mode, until the fix for [#4249](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/4249) broke it in 4.7.12.

We've just started tracking a fix that allows text to be selected and links to be clicked, follow either of the tickets linked here to be updated when we release a fix.

Comment: Still doesn't work in 4.9.7 but does work in 5.1.4 according to what i tested.
According to (https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/4575) even earlier version 5.0.6.
@Spyder you are probably aware of this, i'm writing for others who stumble to this page